# Reference cell on another sheet dynamically?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Basically I have a column of tab/sheet names.  I then want to build hyperlinks to those sheets and make the friendly name a value from the target sheet.  I have the first part down, thanks to a previous question, but is minor as the difference is for the second half I cannot get it right.

Let's say `F4` stores my tab name and it is `Sheet1` (for simplicity's sake)

```
 =HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#'",F4,"'!A1"),"This is a link to Sheet1")
```

That works fine. If I click on it I am taken to cell `A1` on `Sheet1`.  Now I want the "Friendly Name" parameter populated from cell `C8` on `Sheet1`.  Here is one of the things I've tried:

```
 =HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#'",F4,"'!A1"),CONCATENATE(F4,"!",C8))
```

This just results in `Sheet1!`  What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#'",F4,"'!A1"),INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'",F4,"'!C8")))
```